# Google Sheets: Create Average of Numbers ONLY

Tags: google-sheets, error-handling, google-sheets-formula, average, google-query-language

| Test | Mark | Percent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B4 Test | 27/42 | 64% |
| B5 Test |  | #DIV/0! |

[(Google Sheet Here, The Sheet in Question: Results)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQG6wj4SqNffqU1vK32kzF_lNkYM-qqwC3csNPCUw6fdI9AfOV-DIv8OqNS5bPI3BQYzxU7-wkVPExP/pubhtml)

In order to get this 64%, I have used this formula: `=LEFT(D6,2)/RIGHT(D6,2)` and this continues in each cell, the D6 value changing accordingly.
I have made conditional formatting so that where the cell contains **#DIV/0!**, it changes text colour to the same as the background, as you can see if you highlight the cells.

However, I am trying to find an average out of the percentages, but it comes up with the **#DIV/0!** error as it is averaging all cells, not just the number ones. How could I get it to create an average for ***just the percentages*** in each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of:

```
=LEFT(D6,2)/RIGHT(D6,2)
```

use:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(QUERY(, "select "&D6), "offset 1", ))
```

and to get average you can do:

```
=INDEX(AVERAGE(IFERROR(INDEX(SPLIT(D6:D, "/"),,1)/
                       INDEX(SPLIT(D6:D, "/"),,2))))
```

Comment: You can in fact just use a normal =AVERAGE function as it ignores these blank cells

Comment: @taylor.2317 yea, just in case if you want to keep DIV errors